# select by groups - ordered internaly by a value

Tags: mysql

I want something like this:

```
$st = $db->query("select * from posts where position = 'slider' order by inde asc");
```

PLUS

```
$st = $db->query("select * from posts where position = 'right' order by inde asc");
```

PLUS

```
$st = $db->query("select * from posts where position = 'below' order by inde asc");
```

So rows should be selected using this position-order (slider-right-below) but each group inside itself should be ordered by inde.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY FIELD()`. `FIELD()` returns the position of a value in a given list of values.

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE position IN ('slider', 'right', 'below')
ORDER BY FIELD(position, 'slider', 'right', 'below'), inde
```

Comment: Indeed easy to use only disadvantage is that `ORDER BY FIELD` never can use a index

Comment: There are other ways to do it, but I don't think any of them will use an index.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be a query like this:

```
  SELECT p.*
    FROM posts p
   WHERE p.position IN ('slider','right','below')
   ORDER
      BY p.position DESC
       , p.inde ASC
```

(We're noticing that the order of the `position` values can be based on the string values...  we know that `'s' > 'r' > 'b'`.

If we needed those in a different order, we could use an expression to decode the values of position into values that could be sorted by ORDER BY. (And there is are several possible patterns, and wide variety of expressions that we could use.)

---

If the requirement is to run three separate queries (for performance reasons?), something like this would also return the specified result:

```
   ( SELECT p.* FROM posts p WHERE p.position = 'slider' ORDER BY p.inde )
   UNION ALL
   ( SELECT p.* FROM posts p WHERE p.position = 'right'  ORDER BY p.inde )
   UNION ALL
   ( SELECT p.* FROM posts p WHERE p.position = 'below'  ORDER BY p.inde )
```

(MySQL will also allow us to add an ORDER BY after the last paren, to sort the whole set, if we want to more explicitly express the requirement for ordering the result.)